# How can I find the distance between 2 nodes given a list of edges (directed) of a graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shortest-path

Suppose I have the edge set as a list containing the edges as follows:

`E=[(1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 4), (5, 9), (6, 1), (6, 7), (6, 2), (7, 1), (7, 6), (7, 4), (8, 9), (8, 3), (9, 8), (9, 5)]`

I will like to find the shortest path between nodes 8 and 4 (and also considering the case where there are 2 shortest paths of equal distance), given the distance matrix:

`C=[2.5, 5.59, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 5.0, 2.0, 5.59, 5.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0]`

where each element in `C` (say in the i-th position) corresponds to the distance between the 2 nodes of the corresponding edge in `E` (at the i-th position).

I have chanced upon somewhat similar posts which encourages the use of Dijkstra's algorithm, but I have not found one that does it in Python 3.5x (maybe there is but I just cannot find it.. :/)

Thus, to add on to my question above, besides finding the minimum distance between nodes 8 and 4, I will also like to generalize it to finding the minimum distance between any 2 nodes given the edge set and distance matrix.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question ,and BTW what's the desired output?

Comment: @U9-Forward Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit it accordingly.. The desired output is to find the shortest distance between nodes 8 and 4, and also arbitrarily generalize it to any 2 nodes

Comment: Still not clear to me

Comment: Take a look at priority-first search (priority being negative distance traveled) or [best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search). You'll have lots of fun implementing it (hint: start with BFS and then swap FIFO queue with priority queue).

Comment: @U9-Forward Say for e.g., I have 2 edges - (3,8) which consists of nodes 3 and 8, and edge (4,5) which consists of nodes 4 and 5. Then, I will like to find the minimum distance from node 3 to 4. In particular, I will like to have a function (or some method) that enables me to obtain the minimum distance between any 2 nodes.

Comment: @randomir Thanks! I'll read up on these references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `networkx`:

```
import networkx
shortest_path(G, source, target)
```

- **G** is the graph.
- **Source** is the starting node.
- **Target** is the node at the end of the path.

[shortest_path documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html)

Comment: What does G, source and target represent respectively? And what type of input does it take?

Comment: Just added a description of each parameter.  Hope this helps!